# How to parse collections using pyyaml and retrieve values

Tags: python-3.x, pyyaml

I was able to make a simple, straightforward YAML parsing examples work just fine, but I'm having problems with nested structure of the real YAML file that I have to parse.   I'm having problems traversing the collections.   I'm using python3.6, here is the rudimentary code fragment below.

```
import yaml                                                    
with open('action.yml', 'r') as action:                        
    doc = yaml.load(action)                                    
    action = doc["actions"]["a1"]["action"]                    
    print (action)                                             
    tval = doc["actions"]["a1"]["add"]["filters[1]"]["value"]  
    print (tval)                                               
print ('done')
```

Run time error looks like this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):                                  
  File "actionparser.py", line 27, in <module>                      
    tval = doc["actions"]["a1"]["add"]["filters[1]"]["value"]       
KeyError: 'filters[1]'
```

The real YAML input file looks like this.  How do I get actions:a1:add:filters[1]:value and actions:a2:add:filters[1]:value

```
--- 
actions: 
  a1: 
    action: alias
    add: 
      filters: 
        - 
          filtertype: pattern
          kind: prefix
          value: logstash-
        - 
          filtertype: pattern
          kind: regex
          value: ^logstash-dev-firehbridge-cold    <== How do I get this?
        - 
          filtertype: pattern
          kind: timestring
          unit_count: 2
    description: "Add/Remove alias1"
    options: 
      disable_action: false
      ignore_empty_list: true
      name: current_firebridge
      warn_if_no_indices: true
    remove: 
      filters: 
        - 
          filtertype: pattern
          kind: prefix
          value: logstash-
        - 
          filtertype: pattern
          kind: regex
          value: ^logstash-dev-firehbridge-cold
        - 
          filtertype: pattern
          kind: timestring
          unit_count: 2
          value: "%Y.%m.%d"
  a2: 
    action: alias
    add: 
      filters: 
        - 
          filtertype: pattern
          kind: prefix
          value: logstash-
        - 
          filtertype: pattern
          kind: regex
          value: ^logstash-dev-firehbridge-hot    <== and how do I get this?
        - 
          filtertype: pattern
          kind: timestring
          unit_count: 2
    description: "Add/Remove alias2"
    options: 
      disable_action: false
      ignore_empty_list: true
      name: current_firebridge
      warn_if_no_indices: true
    remove: 
      filters: 
        - 
          filtertype: pattern
          kind: prefix
          value: logstash-
        - 
          filtertype: pattern
          kind: regex
          value: ^logstash-dev-firehbridge-hot
        - 
          filtertype: pattern
          kind: timestring
          unit_count: 2
          value: "%Y.%m.%d"
```

Comment: The recommended file extension for YAML files has been `.yaml` since Sep 2006 (https://yaml.org/faq.html)

Answer (score 1):

First of all: PyYAML's default `.load()` is potentially dangerous and
you almost never need it. Use `.safe_load()` instead.

After loading you access any mapping key using pythons `['somekey']`,
key lookup syntax, and any sequence using the list entry indexing (`[somenumber]`).

Assuming your file is named `input.yaml` (with the `<== How do I get this?` removed:

```
import yaml

with open('input.yaml') as fp:
    data = yaml.safe_load(fp)
print(data['actions']['a1']['add']['filters'][1]['value'])
print(data['actions']['a2']['add']['filters'][1]['value'])
```

which gives:

```
^logstash-dev-firehbridge-cold
^logstash-dev-firehbridge-hot
```

Comment: Thanks very much, was so close... yet so far away